# Move items from one listbox to another

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I'd like to move items from one list view to another. adding them to the second one works but the moved entries don't get removed at all.

```
private void MoveSelItems(ListBox from, ListBox to)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < from.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
        {
            to.Items.Add(from.SelectedItems[i].ToString());
        }

        from.Items.Remove(to.SelectedItem);
    }
```

I'm using C# / Winforms / -NET 3.5

Comment: That's because the "to" listbox doesn't autoselect the items you add to it, thus "from.Items.Remove(to.SelectedItem)" does nothing, as "to.SelectedItem" it NOT any of the items just added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code instead at the end of the loop

```
foreach ( var item in new ArrayList(from.SelectedItems) ) {
  from.Items.Remove(item);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private void MoveSelItems(ListBox from, ListBox to)
{
    while (from.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        to.Items.Add(from.SelectedItem[0]);
        from.Items.Remove(from.SelectedItem[0]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void MoveSelItems(ListBox from, ListBox to)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < from.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
        {
            to.Items.Add(from.SelectedItems[i].ToString());
            from.Items.Remove(from.SelectedItems[i]);
        }
    }
```

Though

Items.RemoveAt(i) is probably faster, if that matters.

You may need to create a holding list.

```
    //declare
    List<Object> items = new List<Object>();
    for (int i = 0; i < from.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
    {
        items.Add(from.SelectedItems[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
    {
        to.Items.Add(items[i].ToString());
        from.Items.Remove(items[i]);
    }
```

Comment: I don't believe that will work because you will be changing the collection while you iterate.  You will miss items.

Comment: Good question.  Does editing "Items" change "SelectedItems"?  Probably yes.  In which case he'd need to read them into a temporary array.  Edited to represent that.

Comment: that was was I was thinking because the array is beoming smaller so I'll get an index-error

Answer (score 1):

```
              for (int i = 0; i < ListBox3.Items.Count; i++)
               {
                    ListBox4.Items.Add(ListBox3.Items[i].Text);
                    ListBox3.Items.Remove(ListBox3.SelectedItem);

                }
```