# How to add/move multiselected items from one listbox to another listbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a small prototype that allows to add selected item from one listbox to another. I need to be able to select multiple item from listbox and move them to another and backward - from second listbox to first one. I am wondering if someone has good sample or can modify the code I already have. Thank you in advance.

Two listboxes and buttons XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>    
    <Border Margin="0,40,225,20">
        <ListBox x:Name="LeftListBox" SelectionMode="Multiple"/>
    </Border>
    <Border Margin="0,40,20,20" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FFCECECE" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="169" Padding="5" >
        <ListBox x:Name="RightListBox" BorderThickness="0" />
    </Border>
    <Button x:Name="AddButton" Height="40" Margin="0,3,198,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="AddButton_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="15" Content="▶" />
    <Button x:Name="RemoveButton" Height="40" Margin="0,94,198,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="RemoveButton_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="15" Content="R" />
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class SelectServersUC : UserControl
{

    private ArrayList myDataList = null;
    string currentItemText ;
    int currentItemIndex ;

    public SelectServersUC()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        myDataList = LoadListBoxData();
        LeftListBox.ItemsSource = myDataList;  
    }
    private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myDataList = LoadListBoxData();
        LeftListBox.ItemsSource = myDataList;  
    }
    private ArrayList LoadListBoxData()
    {
        ArrayList itemsList = new ArrayList();
        itemsList.Add("Item1");
        itemsList.Add("Item2");
        itemsList.Add("Item3");
        itemsList.Add("Item4");
        itemsList.Add("Item5");
        itemsList.Add("Item6");
        itemsList.Add("Item7");
        itemsList.Add("Item8");
        itemsList.Add("Item9");
        itemsList.Add("Item10");
        return itemsList;
    }

    private void AddButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Find the right item and it's value and index
        currentItemText = LeftListBox.SelectedValue.ToString();
        currentItemIndex = LeftListBox.SelectedIndex;

        RightListBox.Items.Add(currentItemText);
        if (myDataList != null)
        {
            myDataList.RemoveAt(currentItemIndex);
        }

        // Refresh data binding
        ApplyDataBinding();
    }

    private void RemoveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Find the right item and it's value and index
        currentItemText = RightListBox.SelectedValue.ToString();
        currentItemIndex = RightListBox.SelectedIndex;
        // Add RightListBox item to the ArrayList
        myDataList.Add(currentItemText);

       // LeftListBox.Items.Add(RightListBox.SelectedItem);
        RightListBox.Items.RemoveAt(RightListBox.Items.IndexOf(RightListBox.SelectedItem));

        // Refresh data binding
        ApplyDataBinding();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Refreshes data binding
    /// </summary>
    private void ApplyDataBinding()
    {
        LeftListBox.ItemsSource = null;
        // Bind ArrayList with the ListBox
        LeftListBox.ItemsSource = myDataList;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

just have a look at this

[Move items from one listbox to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644517/move-items-from-one-listbox-to-another)

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/WPFListBoxDataTransfer07272008130032PM/WPFListBoxDataTransfer.aspx

Comment: I need to be able to move multiple items. The sample from c-sharpcorner explains the technique on how to move single item.

Comment: The sample from c-sharpcorner explains the technique on how to move single item in one direction from left listbox to the right listbox.

Comment: I am looking for sample which will allow moving items in both directions from LeftListBox to the RightListBox and from the RightListBox back to the LeftListBox to enable backward interaction.

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class listtolist : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = ListBox1.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (ListBox1.Items[i].Selected)
            {
                ListBox2.Items.Add(ListBox1.Items[i]);
                ListBox1.Items.Remove(ListBox1.Items[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = ListBox2.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (ListBox2.Items[i].Selected)
            {
                ListBox1.Items.Add(ListBox2.Items[i]);
                ListBox2.Items.Remove(ListBox2.Items[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```