# Select a line of text and send it to the adjacent text box VB C#

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio

I'm trying to make a form which would allow a user to select which games they'd like to rent out.

This wizard image is identical to what I'd like to create:

[image: Image of a pop-up box which shows a wizard with 2 text-boxes that has some arrows in between the text-boxes.]

If the user clicks on a line of text I'd like it to be selected and then if an arrow button is pressed, the selected line would move to the adjacent text box.

How could I do this?
Is it possible to do with just 2 text-boxes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Move items from one listbox to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644517/move-items-from-one-listbox-to-another)

Comment: I am not sure how to fix your tags. Do you want VB solution, then tag question with [tag:vb.net], otherwise it's [tag:winforms].

Comment: winforms, I can't figure out how to change the tags

Comment: Those aren't TextBoxes in your image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following code to move the text from listbox to textbox.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("ID");
            listBox1.Items.Add("Name");
            listBox1.Items.Add("Age");
        }

        private void Transfer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.AppendText(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
            listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(listBox1.SelectedIndex);
        }
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this but with the use of c#

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.AppendText($"{listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()}\n");
}
```

Comment: Ah okay, I'm able to add text to the text box but I'm struggling to make the next value to go to the row below. Can you suggest anything for that?

Comment: And then also is it possible to select the text per line in the text box?

Comment: @DanCook you should add a newline `\n` to make sure that the next value will go to the next row.